# standalone client calling remote EJB works in Ubuntu but not in Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, glassfish, ejb, jndi

I run my EJB client together with the EJB in Glassfish 5.1 in the same Windows 10. It works fine. I am trying to port the glassfish to Ubuntu but find that it didn't work if client in Windows and EJB in Ubuntu (win->ubuntu, not ok). However, if client in Ubuntu and EJB in Windows, it works (ubuntu->win, ok). win->win, ok. ubuntu->ubuntu, ok. So I hope somebody here can help me.

For testing, instead of calling the EJBs, I use `Context.list()` to lookup all JNDI in glassfish, and at this end there are some strange result I'll mention at the end.

Here is my client:

```
package test;
public class TestJNDI {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", args[0]);
        Context c = new InitialContext();
        NamingEnumeration<NameClassPair> ne = c.list("");
        if (!ne.hasMore()) {
            System.out.println("c.list empty");
            return;
        }//end if
        while (ne.hasMore()) {
            NameClassPair ncp = ne.next();
            String name = ncp.getName();
            System.out.println(name+"="+ncp.getClassName());
        }//end while
    }//end main
}//end class
```

I've tried to include things like

```
System.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial",
                "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
```

and the others but none of them helps. The client is compiled in windows into `testJNDI.jar` and port to Ubuntu.

First off, I have glassfish running in both ubuntu and windows. Ubuntu EJBs use `mappedName` like `@Singleton(mappedName = "StockFacade")` . Windows has same set of EJBs but all names are prefixed with `win.` like `@Singleton(mappedName = "win.StockFacade")`

Then I run the client in command line. In Ubuntu

```
java -cp testJNDI.jar:/home/me/glassfish5-1/glassfish/lib/gf-client.jar test.TestJNDI win-ip
```

It listed out all EJB names in win glassfish, no prefix. So it works.

Then in windows

```
java -cp testJNDI.jar;d:\glassfish5-1\glassfish\lib\gf-client.jar test.TestJNDI ubu-ip
```

It said `c.list empty`. So it doesn't work.

When I replace `win-ip` and `ubu-ip` of the above with `localhost`, both command works, i.e. ubuntu list without prefix, windows list with prefix. What strange thing is, once I did this, and repeat the second command: windows to ubuntu command using `ubu-ip`, it gives me the windows EJB list instead (i.e. with prefix). only when I shutdown windows glassfish and repeat the command then it gives me `c.list empty`.

So there are two problems: (1) why client in Ubuntu works while same client in Windows doesn't?; (2) why once `localhost` is used in windows, the list seems to stay in some kind of buffer, further access to Ubuntu gives me the windows list? Please help.

EDIT:  Further testing reveal 2 findings:
(1) I found that if I use property `java.naming.provider.url` instead of `org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost` and `....Port` , it always give me the local glassfish's EJBs even if the host url is specified correctly, not work even in  ubuntu->windows cases.
(2) I add another ubuntu to my testing, also with same glassfish and same set of EJBs except names prefixed with `test.` This made me revise my result above. To sum up the new result (client->server=result): ubu1->ubu2 = ubu1 EJBs; ubu2->ubu1 = ubu2 EJBs; ubu-any->win = work ok; win->ubu-any = win EJBs. Any idea?

Comment: Did you check the host file of Windows and Ubuntu? I have faced sometimes the problem that Ubuntu assigns the IP 127.0.1.1 to localhost resulting in all kinds of strange errors. Also (but I guess you checked before) is the Windows Firewall maybe blocking outbound traffic?

Comment: Also found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40045883/windows-client-and-linux-ubuntu-server but no real solution so far.

Comment: @Christoph, thanks for the reply. Hosts file setting is ok. Problem exists also when I use real ip. I've checked the firewall, all java.exe are allowed. The link has very similar problem as mine, but I did not use any VM. Both windows and ubuntu are real boxes.

Comment: I also used PowerShell command `Test Net-Connection ubu-ip -Port 3700` it returns `TcpTestSucceeded : True` . So I think the connection is ok.

Comment: I meant `Test-NetConnection`

Answer (score 0):

I only just saw that you do this:

```
System.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", args[0]);
Context c = new InitialContext();
```

I think you should pass those properties to the `InitialContext` constructor.

```
Properties props = new Properties();  
props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state", "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "127.0.0.1");
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
```

Example taken from here: [Obtaining initial context from remote client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39768754/obtaining-initial-context-from-remote-client)

At least that is what I was doing all the years (when I was still using remote EJBs).

Edit: I think this might also be the issue why it seems that entries are cached. IIRC that can happen when using the default `InitialContext`.